# Locked out of CiviCRM admin

Tags: wordpress, resource-urls

Wordpress 5.3.2    CiviCRM 5.21.0

I've recently upgraded to CiviCRM 5.21.0 successfully and everything was working fine.

Whilst tidying up the site, I inadvertently and stupidly changed the CiviCRM Resource URL to the site URL (not the full path) instead of [civicrm.root]/
I now cannot get into CiviCRM admin through Wordpress admin so am unable to change the resource URL back to how it was.

Does anyone know a way of resettting things through FTP or phpMyAdmin please?

The settings in civicrm-settings.php seem OK.  I've tried reinstalling CiviCRM but still cannot get into Admin.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to override this value in civicrm.settings.php.
There should be a commented out line something like:

```
// $civicrm_setting['URL Preferences']['userFrameworkResourceURL'] = '....';
```

You can uncomment this line by removing the leading '//' and edit the url. 
Make a backup of civicrm.settings.php first.

If you wanted to make a change in the database you can do this by editing the value of civicrm_setting for the row with name "userFrameworkResourceURL".

I'd recommend backing up the database or at least that table first.

If you have logging enabled via (Admin -> System Settings ->  Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.) )

You could find the previous value for this in the log_civicrm_setting table.

Comment: Luke - Thank you for your very prompt reply and for the advice.  I'll give changing the database setting a try.

Comment: Luke - I managed to change the database setting but it didn't immediately solve my problem.  However, I did eventually get into CiviCRM admin where the Resource URL was showing as blank.  I changed it to [civicrm.root]/ and now things seem to be fine.  Thanks again for your help.